# Angular 2 - Provide 3rd-party library with element for rendering

Tags: dom, svg, html5-canvas, angular, getelementbyid

How would I provide a DOM element to a 3rd-party library in Angular 2?

For example, if `Library` is the hypothetical 3rd-party library, and I had to do something like:

```
var fakeId = document.getElementById('fake');  // e.g. canvas or SVG element
var sirRender = Library.confiscate(fakeId);
sirRender.drawMustache();  // accesses canvas context or manipulates SVG
```

I am using `Typescript` and ES6 decorator component syntax.
I'm imagining I can do something inside `ngOnInit` like:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class SirRender {
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    // do something here?
  }
  ...
}
```

---

My specific use case:

I'm trying to use this library called [VexFlow](http://www.vexflow.com/docs/tutorial.html), which takes a canvas element and renders svg.  Specifically, there is an example:

```
var canvas = $("div.one div.a canvas")[0];
var renderer = new Vex.Flow.Renderer(canvas, Vex.Flow.Renderer.Backends.CANVAS);
var ctx = renderer.getContext();
var stave = new Vex.Flow.Stave(10, 0, 500);
stave.addClef("treble").setContext(ctx).draw();
```

So, I'm hoping the answer will work for this ^^ case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you can reference the corresponding `ElementRef` using `@ViewChild`. Something like that:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div #someId>(...)</div>
  `
})
export class Render {
  @ViewChild('someId')
  elt:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let domElement = this.elt.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

`elt` will be set before the `ngAfterViewInit` callback is called. See this doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html.

Comment: Do you know how I can target change detection for that view child?  i.e. I have a subset of my state that requires the canvas to be re-rendered on a change.  Could this be added to the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For HTML elements added statically to your components template you can use [`@ViewChild()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html):

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `<div><span #item></span></div>`
})
export class SirRender {
  @ViewChild('item') item;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    passElement(this.item.nativeElement)
  }
  ...
}
```

This doesn't work for dynamically generated HTML though.

but you can use

```
this.item.nativeElement.querySelector(...)
```

This is frowned upon though because it's direct DOM access, but if you generate the DOM dynamically already you're into this topic already anyway.